# Av Ltspice value for Common Emmiter amplifier is not the calculated one

Tags: amplifier, bjt, common-emitter

I am designing a common emitter amplifier with a total gain of magnitude 5.

I biased the transistor at the Q point I wanted: IcQ = 40mA (checked with LTSPICE). The expression i found for the gain of this circuit is:

$$|A_v| = g_m(R_c||R_L)\frac{R4||R5||r_{\pi}}{R4||R5||r_{\pi} +R_{sig}} = 5$$

Because R4, R5 and RL are much bigger than \$r_{\pi}\$ and \$ R_c\$ correspondingly, this expression becomes:

$$|A_v| = g_mR_c\frac{r_{\pi}}{r_{\pi} +R_{sig}} = 5$$

The expression i use for \$g_m\$ is \$ \frac{I_c}{V_t} \$ and for \$r_{\pi}\$ is \$ \frac{\beta}{g_m} \$. I am using 25mV for thermal voltage.

In  this case Rsig is 100Ω. Solving for Rc, I obtain a value of 8.13 ohms.
But LTSPICE circuit gain is 3.3. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Looks like C3 might be a bit small for such high emitter current.

Comment: If you want a gain of 5 use an extra series Re for better linearity.  Then R2//R1 / Re =5 or remove C3 and make R2//R1 = 5 * 220

Comment: Daniel, I need to ask why EG = 0.01. Normally, this is more like 1.1, isn't it?

Comment: Daniel, and finally why not try and increase the capacitor values to about 20 mF? (Especially C3.) The reactance is way too high, right now.

Comment: @glen_geek  thank you, i changed it to 30u and Av is now 4.4

Comment: What is the asymmetry, i.e. gain for each peak?

Answer (score 1):

> What am i doing wrong?

1. Vb is far too high with R5:R4 ratio thus Ve is too high reducing the available output swing on Vc
2. The precision on R4 has too many significant figures considering tolerances and error in 1.
3. The use of C3 in a low gain Common Emitter (CE) amplifier requires a fixed Re to control the gain, rather than Ic and  which causes a large variation on Vbe and makes the current on Ic quadratic and same for gain , resulting in very asymmetric  gain for each peak.
4. Collector R2 is far too low and thus your quiescent operating point from 1. should result in little (3.3) or no gain except for very small signals as the Vc will be near 12V.

### What to do?

1. Besides Av=-5 what other specs are important?

   - Vc = 50% of (12V-Ve) + Vce(min)=1V.
   - Ic max = ?
   - Rout = Rc  , choose Rc/Re=|Av|
   - Rin = ? >> 100 Ohms. E.g. hFE * Re
   - Vout max swing = ??
   - compute impedance of C (f) relative to R impedance.
2. Start with good DC specs then recompute gain for Av=-5 to choose all the R values, allowing for input attenuation.